# Modify Quantity of certain products in woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to make it so that the quantity in order emails show up as double for specific products only. Ive modified email-order-items.php as follows (not working):

Added on line 28: `$product_id = $product->get_product_id();`
Added on line 79:

```
if( $product_id == 6960) {
    $qty_display = '<del>' . esc_html( $qty ) . '</del> <ins>' . esc_html( $qty * 2 ) . '</ins>';
}
```

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-order-items.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function for this, 
If you do not know how or where you can add this code, take a look at the following link

https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-pasting-snippets-from-the-web-into-wordpress/

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity( $qty_display, $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    if ( $product_id == 6960 ) {
        $qty_display = $qty_display * 2;
    }

    return $qty_display; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
```